# Postgres - Update system column in multiple tables with single query

Tags: postgresql

I want to update **sysOperatorId** column in all tables in single query.

```
update (SELECT
   tablename
FROM
   pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE
   (schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema') order by tablename) 
set sysOperatorId = 'xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx' where sysOperatorId = 'xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx'
```

Above sub query returns the tables which are created by user. In each table i have a column sysOperatorId, I want to update that column.

Comment: Above sub query returns the tables which are created by user. In each table i have a column **sysOperatorId**, I want to update that column.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic SQL for that.

Something like the following (untested):

```
do
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_rec record;
  l_id1 text := 'xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx';
  l_id2 text := 'xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx';
begin
  for l_rec in select tablename 
               from pg_catalog.tables
               where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  loop
     l_sql := format('update %I set sysoperatorid = $1 where sysoperatorid = $2', l_rec.tablename);
     execute l_sql 
       using l_id1, l_id2;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

The [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function generates an UPDATE statement using the value from `pg_tables.tablename` as the target table. The `I%` is a placeholder for an identifier and will properly treat tables that need quoting.

Then this SQL string is executed, passing the two IDs as parameters (rather than including them as constants in the SQL string).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid for loop??

Comment: @NarendarReddyM: no, there is not. But what's the problem? That's effectively  a single statement.

Comment: I'm thinking about time, I Have 100+ tables and some tables has 200000+ records.

Comment: If you need to update 100 * 200000 rows, no solution will change that, regardless if you find one without a loop or not